# an AsyncTask which is started from OnCreate of an activity, only if such an AsyncTask is not currently running. How might I implement this?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, threadpool

On opening a new screen (activity)  I want my program to start a new Async Task which will be running every X interval forever.  I do not want to create one, if another is already running.

I have tried many things with global variables, shared preference flags etc.  Is there a way I can extend AsyncTask but alter the thread pool to 1 so that no duplicates will be initiated?

Or is there a more obvious solution to this problem?

Note: Problem with Preferences is that if the device is restarted it might save the flag in a permanent "true" indicating there is a Task running when there is not, preventing a new task from running.

Am I daft for attempting such a thing??

Answer (score 2):

Store Asynctask in a field

```
task =  new NewAsyncTask().execute();
```

Everytime check if finished and reassign to the same field new Asynctask

```
if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
  task =  new NewAsyncTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to run on the background every so second then you will need to use Service or IntentService. In fact, if you use Service then you wont help to worry about thread duplication since there will always only one running on the background unless you create multiple service.

Comment: I don't think I want to use a service because I do want to be able to manipulate and update the UI thread.  This background task may interact with the main activity window.

Is this incorrect?  I need things like the context, activity, and I know that OnProgress and OnPostExecute are designed to work with the UI thread.  Except come to think of it most of my Task is running in DoInBackground. Not sure how Progress works but I was thinking I could have DoInBackground tell OnPrograss to say: update a UI listview?

Comment: You can still interact with UI thread with service. On your Service, you can sendBroadCast(Intent). Then on your UI thread, you can make inner class extends BroadcastReceiver which implements onReceive()

Comment: Can you see anything wrong with a service which ran on an infinite loop with thread.sleep(xxxxx)?

Comment: No problem whatsoever. That is the whole point of a service. You can use GlobalApplication to control when to start and when to stop the service as needed.

Comment: What advantages do you see this having over say, SingletonTask or Async with a field?  Sorry to drain your time but I'm here to learn from very little background.  Also what is "Global Application?" a method?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I am glad to help :) I meant global context. So what you want to do is create a class that extends Application then specify it within your Android Manifest file. Once done that, you can create a boolean call isServiceRunning. Once you had that, the rest is trivial. Run your service while(isServiceRunning)..If you want to stop the service at any point in any activity, use the global context and set isServiceRunning = false.

Answer (score 0):

Use the singleton pattern, something like:

```
public class SingletonTask extends AsyncTask {
  private static SingletonTask instance;

  public static startTask(params, callback) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SingletonTask(params, callback);
      instance.execute();
    }
  }
  ....

  onPostExecute() {
    instance = null;
  }
}
```

Then from your activity just call `SingletonTask.startTask(...)`.

Disclaimer: Typed on the fly, will not compile.

Comment: AsyncTask object is used only once.